# PG::UndefindColumn: ERROR on only at action test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm getting this test error when I run my test by "`bundle exec rake test`"

> ERROR["test_unsuccessful_edit", UsersEditTest...
>   ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error:
>   PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column groups_users.group_id does not
>   exist

It works fine on development. My test script is below.

```
# test "unsuccessful edit" do
#   log_in_as(@user)
#   get edit_user_path(@user)
#   assert_template 'users/edit'
#   patch user_path(@user), user: { name: "",
#   email: "foo@invalid",
#   password: "foo",
#   password_confirmation: "bar",
#  }
#   assert_template 'users/edit'
# end
```

As you can see, I skipped this test since it apparently nothing wrong in the development environment.

The error message is saying "group_id" column does not exist in table "groups_users". But it's actually exist since I've run migration and checked database/behavior by hands.

Is there any way to make this test script work?

In my models, as you may be guessing, I have below relationships method.

• User.rb

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, join_table: :groups_users, dependent: :destroy
```

• Group.rb

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user, join_table: :groups_users
```

And addition, my controller is something like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    .
    .
    .
    def new
        @user = User.new
        @groups = Group.all
    end
    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @groups = Group.all
    end
    def update
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
            flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
            redirect_to @user
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
    .
    .
    .
    private
        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email,
            :password, :password_confirmation, 
            :group_ids => [])
        end
end
```

And my migration file looks like this:

```
class GroupsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :groups_users, :id => false do |t|
        t.integer :group_id
        t.integer :user_id
    end
  end
end
```

There is no validation for these groups values to be present. Please let me know if you have any idea or questions.

Thanks,

Comment: Check the existence of test db. Try `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create`.

Comment: If db exists run: `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:reset`.

Comment: I did `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop` and `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create` and `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate` and then try user edit test again. Now I've got `ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass`. In my view code is something like this:
`<%= collection_check_boxes(:user, :group_ids, @groups, :id, :name) %>`

Comment: Seems like you need to seed data (users, ...) to the database.

Comment: It's happening in Test environment. It's totally works fine on development. I will check `test/fixtures` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure this out. I have add `@groups = Group.all` in `def update` action in User controller as you can see in below then unsuccessful user edit test be able to map all of group names via `collection_check_boxes` helper.

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @groups = Group.all
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

The reason is it seems works fine on development is `group` uses its own model/controller and I migrated with `groups_users` many_to_many method.

Hence when groups appear on `User > Edit` it just works fine without any error on development environment since it doses not use `User > Update` method.

While any of User's values that have been modified using `User > Update`, `groups` only using its own `Group > Edit & Update` method. But when it comes to the test, it becomes matters to be tested. Without adding `@groups = Group.all` in `User > any action` except `update` and `create`, Rails cannot map `groups` in development/production environment neither.